# Preventing Amazon from automatically unsubscribing me from my questions

Tags: amazon

Whenever I ask a question on an Amazon product on Amazon, after one or two days Amazon automatically unsubscribes me from my question, and I get an email about it. Is there any way to prevent Amazon from automatically unsubscribing me from my questions?

Here are the sort of emails I receive:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon has changed its policy and as of now (2020-12-21) doesn't automatically unsubscribe from one's questions:

[image]